# how to emplace_back(pair) efficiently?

Tags: c++, std-pair, emplace

I have

```
using namespace std;   // for convenience in SO question only
vector<pair<array<int,3>, int>> foo;
```

and want to `emplace_back` an element with `pair::first` holding `{i,j,k}` and `pair::second` holding `q`. The only way I could get this compiling was with the rather clumsy

```
foo.emplace_back(piecewise_construct,
                 forward_as_tuple(i,j,k),
                 forward_as_tuple(q));
```

Is this efficient (i.e. is it *guaranteed* that the `tuple`s will be optimised away)? Or is there another way that is *guaranteed* efficient?

(I tried

```
foo.emplace_back(std::initializer_list<int>{i,j,k}, q);
```

but to no avail with gcc 4.8.1). I know that I can avoid this problem by defining

```
struct element : std::pair<std::array<int,3>,int>
{
  element(int i, int j, int k, int q)
  { first={i,j,k}; second=q; }
};

vector<element> foo;
foo.emplace_back(i,j,k,q);
```

but I'd prefer to do without such extra code.

Comment: What is a `pair<array<int,3>,int>` ? Maybe you can come up with a simple name, then create a simple type... use that type from there on? For anyone looking at your code `pair<array<int,3>,int>` is not really helping describe what it is meant to represent, a bit more typing on your side to create a type will help all uses, including your's.

Comment: Can't get it to compile on GCC 5.1 : `error: no matching function for call to 'std::array<int, 3ul>::array(int&, int&, int&)'`. What compiler are you using ?

Comment: Quentin, that is because I actually didn't do what I said in the question, sorry. I didn't use `array<int,3>`, but some other vector-like (in the physical meaning of 'vector') type.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`std::array<T, N>` doesn't have any constructor taking a `std::initializer_list<U>` for any `U`, not even for `U = T`. Don't mistake the fact that it can be initialised from a braced-init-list for the presence of such a constructor.

Instead, actually create an array.

```
foo.emplace_back(std::array<int,3>{i,j,k}, q);
```

There are hardly any guarantees about efficiency, and this is not guaranteed to be more efficient than your tuple approach. In practice, it shouldn't make much of a difference, I expect implementations to optimise both forms of `emplace_back` to the same machine code. If you really care, and you doubt that, measure it.

Comment: Well, actually in the real application I don't use `array<int,3>` but some other vector-like (in the physics meaning of 'vector') type.

Comment: Then don't write `array<int,3>` there, but your real vector-like type. :)

Comment: But that wont' make for a MCVE either :(